# Getting last values for week in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like know how to get the last value for each week.

Let's say I have the next values

```
-- Table 1 --
day          value
2018-03-12   32
2018-02-14   42
2018-03-16   62
2018-03-19   82
2018-03-20   92
2018-03-21   102
2018-03-27   112
2018-03-28   122
2018-03-29   132
```

How can I get the next values which are the last values for each week. Assuming the week start on Monday.

```
Day        Value
2018-03-16 62
2018-03-21 102
2018-03-29 132
```

I have everything settled here [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec12/1)

Comment: good job on setting up sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by YEARWEEK()

> ```
> create table tbl (day date, value int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> ('2018-03-12',   32),
> ('2018-02-14',   42),
> ('2018-03-16',   62),
> ('2018-03-19',   82),
> ('2018-03-20',   92),
> ('2018-03-21',   102),
> ('2018-03-27',   112),
> ('2018-03-28',   122),
> ('2018-03-29',   132);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select day, yearweek(day) from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> day        | yearweek(day)
> :--------- | ------------:
> 2018-03-12 |        201810
> 2018-02-14 |        201806
> 2018-03-16 |        201810
> 2018-03-19 |        201811
> 2018-03-20 |        201811
> 2018-03-21 |        201811
> 2018-03-27 |        201812
> 2018-03-28 |        201812
> 2018-03-29 |        201812
> ```

> ```
> select day, value
> from tbl
> join (select max(day) mday
>       from   tbl
>       group by yearweek(day)) t
> on day = mday
> ```
>
> ```
> day        | value
> :--------- | ----:
> 2018-02-14 |    42
> 2018-03-16 |    62
> 2018-03-21 |   102
> 2018-03-29 |   132
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=557e894dc3a74099d5d1956939e504b5)*

Answer (score 3):

You can get the week number of day then get the max value per week number.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join (
select week(day) as wknum, 
       max(day) as day
from   table1 
group by week(day)
     ) t2
on t1.day=t2.day


Result:
day         value
2018-03-16  62
2018-03-21  102
2018-03-29  132
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses window functions and picks the latest date within the week.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html

I use SQL Server, but I believe this is the MySQL equivalent:

```
with cte AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WEEKOFYEAR([day]) ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK([day]) DESC) AS counter_
from #table1 
)

SELECT [day], [value] 
FROM cte 
WHERE counter_ = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do it in SQL Server - Use mysql equivalent

```
select b.day, b.value from (
select datepart(ww,day) a, max(day) b
from yourtable
group by datepart(ww,day))a
join yourtable b on a.a=datepart(ww,b.day) and a.b=b.day
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ec12/66):

= Order by the closest to the end of every week

= Group by week

```
SELECT day, value
FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY DATEDIFF(day + INTERVAL 6 - weekday(day) DAY, day) ASC) t
GROUP BY week(day);
```